# Dagger 2 doesnt generate code. Unresolved reference: DaggerAppComponent

Tags: android, kotlin

I have been trying to generate code in project for a week. The problem is that after i added AppComponent, Module, dependencies and plugin it doesnt work. I got compilation error. Then i repeated all this in new empty project an it works properly.
My Android Gradle plugin version:7.1.0
Gradle version:7.3

**My AppComponent**

`@Component(modules = [AppModule::class]) interface AppComponent { fun mainRepository(): MainRepository }`

**AppModule**

@Module
object AppModule {

```
@Provides
fun provideMainRepository(): MainRepository {
    return MainRepository()
}
```

}

**Gradle file**

```
plugins {
id 'com.android.application'
id 'kotlin-android'
id 'com.google.gms.google-services'
id 'kotlin-kapt'
id 'com.google.firebase.crashlytics'
id 'kotlin-parcelize'
```

}

android {
compileSdkVersion 31
buildToolsVersion "30.0.3"

```
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.flametech.vaytoday"
    minSdkVersion 22
    targetSdkVersion 30
    versionCode 58
    versionName "2.19"
    multiDexEnabled = true
    testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}

buildFeatures {
    viewBinding = true
}

buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_11
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_11
}
kotlinOptions {
    jvmTarget = '11'
}
```

}

dependencies {

```
implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.7.0'
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.4.1'
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.5.0'
implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.3'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:20.0.0'
implementation 'androidx.room:room-runtime:2.3.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage-ktx:20.0.0'
implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
implementation 'androidx.databinding:databinding-runtime:4.1.3'
implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-common-java8:2.3.1'
implementation 'androidx.fragment:fragment-ktx:1.3.6'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:26.0.0')
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-ktx'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'
...

implementation "com.google.dagger:dagger:2.40.5"
kapt "com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.40.5"
```

}

**Error**

```
 Unresolved reference: DaggerAppComponent
```

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugKotlin'.

> Compilation error. See log for more details

**Stactrace**

```
> Configure project :app
```

WARNING:The option setting 'android.overridePathCheck=true' is experimental.
The current default is 'false'.

> Task :app:kaptDebugKotlin
> app/build/tmp/kapt3/stubs/debug/com/flametech/vaytoday/domain/database/AppDatabase.java:7: warning: Schema export directory is not provided to the annotation processor so we cannot export the schema. You can either provide `room.schemaLocation` annotation processor argument OR set exportSchema to false.
> public abstract class AppDatabase extends androidx.room.RoomDatabase {
> ^

> Task :app:compileDebugKotlin FAILED
> e: app/src/main/java/MainActivity.kt: (51, 42): Unresolved reference: DaggerAppComponent

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugKotlin'.

> Compilation error. See log for more details

- Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 8.0.

You can use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings and determine if they come from your own scripts or plugins.

See https://docs.gradle.org/7.3/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings

BUILD FAILED in 18s

**AppComponent creating in MainActivity**

```
   override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    val appComponent: AppComponent = DaggerAppComponent.create()}
```

**SOLUTION!!!**
The problem is solved. I checked my dependencies and understood that i had import in my AppComponent and in my Module like this `import com.google.android.datatransport.runtime.dagger.Component`

But the right import was `import dagger.Component`

Comment: And where is the code line that builds `AppComponent`?

Comment: @Onik i have updated the questions. It at the bottom.

Comment: i solved the problem and updated the question

Answer (score 1):

The problem is solved. I checked my dependencies and understood that i had import in my AppComponent and in my Module like this

```
import com.google.android.datatransport.runtime.dagger.Component
```

But the right import was `import dagger.Component`